# Template specialization for multiple tags in any order

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Say I have a class `event_base` defined like so

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event_base{
    public:
        using delegate_type = std::function<void(Args...)>;
        using id_type = size_t;

    protected:
        std::vector<std::tuple<delegate_type, id_type>> m_funcs;
};
```

and a couple empty tag structures defined like this

```
struct mutable_tag{};
struct callable_tag{};
```

Then I want to be able to derive from that base class based on either(or both) of the tags given in the template pack

For a single tag:

```
template<class ...>
class event;

template<typename ... Args>
class event<mutable_tag, Args...>: public event_base<Args...>{};

template<typename ... Args>
class event<callable_tag, Args...>: public event_base<Args...>{};
```

Then for multiple tags:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event<mutable_tag, callable_tag, Args...>: public event<mutable_tag, Args...>, public event<callable_tag, Args...>{};

template<typename ... Args>
class event<callable_tag, mutable_tag, Args...>: public event<mutable_tag, callable_tag, Args...>{};
```

Now I want to be able to specialize the class for when no tags are specified

E.g:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event<Args...>: event<callable_tag, mutable_tag, Args...>{};
```

Now that obviously won't work because it doesn't actually specialize the class; but I don't know what to write instead of this. I want to be able to derive from the already defined classes with tags so that I don't have to redundantly define operators and methods.

How could this be achieved?

Comment: Why do you think you would be able to initialize a reference of the subclass type with an object of the base class?

Comment: @DarkFalcon you're absolutely right, now that is taken care of!

Comment: OK. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish by doing this? I don't understand what you want to do that can't be done by putting code either in `event_base` or in the non-specialized `event<Args...>`

Comment: @pmr that was a typo, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Why not just introduce a layer of indirections with using declarations? `using mutable_event = event_impl<mutable_tag>` and so on. Much clearer and easier to read, but might not work if you need to work with it programmatically.

Comment: I think boost has at least a partial solution in their named template parameters sublibrary: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#class-template-parameter-support

Comment: You could use type functions that separate the template parameter pack into tags and non-tags.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to be able to specialize the class for when no tags are specified

In fact, no, it is not a specialization but the normal case, so use:

```
template<typename ... Args>
class event : event<callable_tag, mutable_tag, Args...>{};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/jOgdY1)